# How to make Toolbar unsticky at the top?

Tags: 7, javascript

Drupal 7

The toolbar is sticky at the top even you scroll down the page.

How can I make it unsticky at the top?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Seeds Toolbar for Drupal 8. https://www.drupal.org/project/seeds_toolbar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fixed position is hard-coded into the toolbar.css file included with the core module.

To override it add the following to a CSS file that you're including with the admin theme:

```
#toolbar {
  position: static !important;
}

body.toolbar, body.toolbar-drawer {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```

The `!important` declarations may or not be necessary depending on the order of inclusion...try without it first, and if it doesn't work, try adding it.

Comment: so the sticky effect is made by the css not javascript?

Comment: @gilzero Yep, it's simply done with `position: fixed` on the `#toolbar` element. The body needs padding when this is the case, but doesn't if the element is not fixed, hence the need to remove it when making the toolbar non-fixed

Comment: "auto" is not a valid value for position in CSS 2.1 or CSS 3.  The default value is "static".